# Reading XML element occurrences using PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, xmltable, oracle-xml-db

I have this XML.

```
<a>
   <b>b1</b>
   <c>c1</c>
   <b>b2</b>
   <c>c2</c2>
</a>
```

I want to be able to extract the values of elements 'b' and 'c' using PL\SQL. I'm using Oracle 10g.

So far I have this,

```
  SELECT   XML.b                    
       , XML.c
    FROM XMLTable (
           '/a' PASSING p_xml
              COLUMNS
                 b            VARCHAR(2) PATH 'b/.'
               , c            VARCHAR(2) PATH 'c/.'
    ) XML
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
19279. 00000 -  "XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence" 
*Cause:    The XQuery sequence passed in had more than one item.
*Action:   Correct the XQuery expression to return a single item sequence.
```

Then I tried this:

```
  SELECT   XML.b                    
         , XML1.c
    FROM XMLTable (
           '/a/b' PASSING p_xml
              COLUMNS
                 b            VARCHAR(2) PATH '.'
    ) XML,
        XMLTable (
           '/a/c' PASSING p_xml
              COLUMNS
                 c            VARCHAR(2) PATH '.'
    ) XML1
```

But the results were:

```
b1,c1
b1,c2
b2,c1
b2,c2
```

When I want only:
    b1
    c1
    b2
    c2

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt run it but as far as i see below code should work ;

```
DECLARE
vs_Xml VARCHAR2(32000):= '<INPUT>
  <A>
    <B>1</B>
  </A>
  <A>
    <B>2</B>
  </A>
</INPUT>';

vx_ParameterList   XMLTYPE;
vx_Parameter       XMLTYPE;
vn_ParameterIndex  NUMBER;
vs_Key             VARCHAR2(64);
vs_XPath           VARCHAR2(255);
vs_Value           VARCHAR2(10000);

BEGIN
vx_ParameterList := xmltype(vs_Xml);
vn_ParameterIndex := 1;
vs_XPath := '/INPUT/A'; 

WHILE vx_ParameterList.existsNode(vs_XPath || '[' || vn_ParameterIndex || ']') = 1 LOOP
  vx_Parameter := vx_ParameterList.extract(vs_XPath || '[' || vn_ParameterIndex || ']');

  vs_Value := vx_Parameter.extract('//B/text()').GetStringVal();
  vn_ParameterIndex := vn_ParameterIndex + 1;

  dbms_output.put_line(vs_Value);
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust the xquery expression in the `XMLTABLE` command. The basic idea is to produce a stream of xml records each of which can be mapped to columns of a database record.

The obstacle in the original xml is that the xpath axis `/a` returns - phrased sloppily - the content of *all* xml records.

The solution is to build an iterator over `/a` that delivers the xml records one-by-one (technically: wrapped in an synthetic `x` element).

The following can be issued from sqlplus:

```
      SELECT   myxml.b
           ,   myxml.c                            
        FROM XMLTable (
'for $i in (1, let $x := fn:count(/a/b) return $x )
 let $b := /a/b[$i], $c := /a/c[$i]
 return <x>
           <b>{$b}</b>
           <c>{$c}</c>
        </x>
' PASSING XMLTYPE(
'<a>
   <b>b1</b>
   <c>c1</c>
   <b>b2</b>
   <c>c2</c>
</a>')
                  COLUMNS
                     b            VARCHAR(2) PATH '/x/b'
                   , c            VARCHAR(2) PATH '/x/c'
        ) myxml
;
```

**Update**

In order to allow for arbitrary number of `b`/`c` children, the following line

```
for $i in (1, let $x := fn:count(/a/b) return $x )
```

replaces the original

```
for $i in (1, 2)
```

in the above expression.

**Reference**

More info about XQuery syntax can be found in the [W3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#doc-xquery-FLWORExpr) (deep-links to the syntax doc forthe so-called FWLOR expressions).